# Is there a way that someone else can undo a Paint delete?

Tags: microsoft-paint

So speaking of the Windows *Paint* App, let's say I deleted a significant portion of a soon-to-be BMP or JPG file and then uploaded the file online.

Is there any way someone can restore the deleted part of the picture?

Comment: Have you uploaded the file before?  Does the website keep versions or does it overwrite the previous one?

Comment: 1. Nope the first time I uploaded it. 2. I'm not sure but if the previous versions are kept they are not displayed on the main post.

Answer (score 1):

If you overlay any part of an image with any solid colour, be it black, white, red, anything, then save it as a flat file - jpg, png, bmp etc, then no part of the underlying image can ever be restored - so long as the coverage was entire.

See…

> [image]

You can just about make out bits round the edges where the coverage is not complete, but the majority of the hidden area is gone forever.

Comment: What if instead of an overlay, I cut out a significant part of the picture?

Comment: With scissors?  :P  if you cut it, it will be filled by 'background', which is essentially exactly the same as paining over the foreground. Once saved as a flat file, ie nothing with layers, then recovery is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tetsujin's answer. I would add though, that if you are not sure if your picture has layers or how to remove them, you could always save a cropped screenshot of the edited picture.  In this way you are essentially creating a flat copy of the picture AND removing any exif data saved to the original file.

Comment: If you save jpg, png or bmp, they are incapable of storing layers. A screenshot is a quick & dirty way to do it, though, for sure.